# Wp_remote_post not posting data

Tags: wp-remote-post

This works in php:

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
        array(
            'api' => get_option('API_key'),
            'gw' => '1'
        )
    );

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

    $api_response = file_get_contents('https://myurl.com/api', false, $context);
```

However, this does not work in Wordpress:

```
$args = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'headers'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'sslverify' => false,
        'api' => get_option('API_key'),
        'gw' => '1'
    );

    $api_response = wp_remote_post('https://myurl.com/api', $args);
```

It basicly should do the same, but wordpress somehow fails to send the POST data. I want to send the data to server and get the HTML response as `$api_response`.

Comment: Looking at [the options](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Http/request/#parameters) that `wp_remote_post()` accepts, I don't see `api` or `gw`. What does `var_dump( $api_response );` give you in your WordPress code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’re passing request params incorrectly.

Take a look at [Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post). You can find such example in there:

> ```
> $response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
>   'method' => 'POST',
>   'timeout' => 45,
>   'redirection' => 5,
>   'httpversion' => '1.0',
>   'blocking' => true,
>   'headers' => array(),
>   'body' => array( 'username' => 'bob', 'password' => '1234xyz' ),
>   'cookies' => array()
>    )
> );
> ```

So in your case it should look something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'headers'  => array(
        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ),
    'sslverify' => false,
    'body' => array(
        'api' => get_option('API_key'),
        'gw' => '1'
    )
);

$api_response = wp_remote_post('https://myurl.com/api', $args);
```

Comment: Thank you very much that works. I misunderstood WP documentation, did not know posting data works via Body attribute. Thanks a lot!